# Does attempting to hack into a system constitute a cybercrime by itself?

Tags: criminal-law, hacking

If someone tries to attack or gain unauthorized access to a given system but fails eventually, could that person get arrested for the mere attempt?

I know laws differ from one state/country to another, but is there some sort of a generic answer?

Comment: Attempting to do something that is a crime is almost always a crime.

Comment: See [here: At least the U.K. has a Criminal Attempts Act](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/15739/10)!

Answer (score 1):

In the US, hacking i.e. gaining unauthorized access violates [18 USC 1030(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1030). 
18 USC 1030(b) then says

> Whoever conspires to commit or attempts to commit an offense under
>   subsection (a) of this section shall be punished as provided in
>   subsection (c) of this section.

So conspiracy and attempts are treated the same as success.